# Applying IIS rewrite rules from multiple web.configs for single request

Tags: iis, rewrite, iis-8.5, web.config

I am trying to configure a directory structure in an IIS website with rewrite rules applying at various levels. For example, consider the following structure:

```
Default Web Site
├─ web.config
└─ v1
   ├─ web.config
   └─ wwwroot
      └─ hello.txt
```

I want to be able to access `hello.txt` through http://localhost/hello.txt. I have configured the `web.config` at the website root level like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to v1" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="^(?!v1).*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="v1\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I have configured the `web.config` in the `v1` directory like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to wwwroot" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="^(?!wwwroot).*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The one-level rewrite works when I access http://localhost/v1/hello.txt, but the two-level rewrite doesn't work for http://localhost/hello.txt. The IIS error page shows that the request is still resolving to the physical path `…\v1\hello.txt` rather than `…\v1\wwwroot\hello.txt`; see https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjdH5.png. Note that changing the rewrites to redirects allows the file to be served successfully.

Is there a way of getting this to work, or it is some limitation of the URL Rewrite Module? Microsoft seems to claim that this is supported in the [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rules-inheritance):

> **Rules Inheritance**
>
> If rules are defined on multiple configuration levels, the URL Rewrite Module evaluates the rules in the following order:
>
> 1. Evaluate all the global rules.
> 2. Evaluate a rule set that includes distributed rules from parent configuration levels as well as rules from the current configuration level. The evaluation is performed in a parent-to-child order, which means that parent rules are evaluated first and the rules defined on a last child level are evaluated last.

I'm aware that I can make the `web.config` at the website root level reference the inner `wwwroot` directory directly (through `url="v1\wwwroot\{R:0}"`). However, I don't want to do this. I will eventually be extending the outer `web.config` to support other versions (`v2`, `v3`, …), which may or may not also have a `wwwroot` subdirectory, so it would be much cleaner to maintain any version-specific rewrites to inner subdirectories in the version-specific `web.config`.

I've tried using Failed Request Tracing. The outer rule, `Rewrite to v1`, is logged to run successfully. There is no mention of the inner rule, `Rewrite to wwwroot`.